# PHP SoapClient is this an extension or PEAR

Tags: php, soap

I am a bit confused I read years ago about PHP SoapClient being better than NUSOAP as it was a C extension, which would mean far better performance. Recently I saw SoapClient on PEAR so decided to download it to see what was going on inside. From what I could see it was just a PHP package using Curl, am I right is there no higher level support for Soap.

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP 5.0 SoapClient is an extension.
See [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php)

Comment: I am not really too sure that is a C level extension to PHP, I would agree that since version 5 it has been bundled